# How do I get suds to send optional, empty elements?

Tags: python, soap, suds

I have a SOAP API and I'm trying to call a method via suds (python):

```
DoSomething(ns1:DoSomethingRequest Input, )
```

`DoSomethingRequest` looks something like this:

```
    (DoSomethingRequest){
   Person = 
      (Person){
         Name = "Joe"
         Age = 32
      }
   ActionOne = None
   ActionTwo = None
   ActionThree = None
 }
```

In the type definition, the action params are all optional. To invoke a specific action, you set `DoSomethingRequest.ActionOne = [an instance of ActionOneRequest]`. This is all fine (I can perform `ActionOne`), except that I'm trying to call `ActionThree`, and `ActionThreeRequest` is an empty complex element. When I set `DoSomethingRequest.ActionThree = ActionThreeRequest`, a print on `DoSomethingRequest` gives:

```
    (DoSomethingRequest){
   Person = 
      (Person){
         Name = "Joe"
         Age = 32
      }
   ActionOne = None
   ActionTwo = None
   ActionThree = <empty>
 }
```

and the XML sent to the server excludes `ActionThree`. If I intercept the code with pdb and add an empty element `<ActionThree></ActionThree>`, it works.

Looking at the code, for suds:

```
class ObjectAppender(Appender):
    """
    An L{Object} appender.
    """

    def append(self, parent, content):
        object = content.value
        if self.optional(content) and footprint(object) == 0:
            return
        child = self.node(content)
        parent.append(child)
        for item in object:
            cont = Content(tag=item[0], value=item[1])
            Appender.append(self, child, cont)
```

and

```
def footprint(sobject):
    """
    Get the I{virtual footprint} of the object.
    This is really a count of the attributes in the branch with a significant value.
    @param sobject: A suds object.
    @type sobject: L{Object}
    @return: The branch footprint.
    @rtype: int
    """
    n = 0
    for a in sobject.__keylist__:
        v = getattr(sobject, a)
        if v is None: continue
        if isinstance(v, Object):
            n += footprint(v)
            continue
        if hasattr(v, '__len__'):
            if len(v): n += 1
            continue
        n +=1
    return n
```

I don't use SOAP often, so I assume I'm either using the API incorrectly, or am using suds incorrectly. Or, maybe the service API is nonstandard.

Do you know why there's a problem and how best to solve it?

Strangely, the opposite question is on SO: [Suds generates empty elements; how to remove them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388180/suds-generates-empty-elements-how-to-remove-them) Unfortunately, it's a lot easier to remove empty elements than to figure out which elements were removed and re-add them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the specs and talking to experts, I didn't see anything that indicated that it's okay for a SOAP library to strip out optional, empty elements.

There's a patched version of suds on [github](https://github.com/yunesj/suds).

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes across this question, and doesn't find an answer. A similar situation happened to me. I was attempting to send the following body in a SOAP request,

```
<ns0:list><ns0:filter xsi:type="ns0:UserFilter"/></ns0:list>
```

My first attempt, I created the element using the `suds.client.factory` and send that with nothing configured. That resulted in the following body,

```
<ns0:list><filter/></ns0:list>
```

I next tried creating an `Element` by hand and setting the `type` attribute manually. That got me the same envelope body.

After digging through the source code, I figured out that the `SoapClient.send()` method was stripping my attribute in the `sax.Document.plain()` method.

Looking at the code, I figured out that I could set the `prettyxml=True` option on the suds client and that wouldn't strip the attribute.