# Using suds for python as a SOAP client and failing to handle NoneType

Tags: c#, python, web-services, soap

So i'm using suds-jurko for python3 and I have a value in my request like this:

```
`Date = None`
```

Date is not a required field.  The issue I'm running into is when it processes the request, I get the error:

`WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://webservices.soapclient.com/v11:request. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type WebServices.Posting.Request. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'DateTime'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.'`

Any clue how I can pass a valid NoneType so that my client won't convert it to an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

If the Date field is optional, you should completely skip it and not try to pass any value at all (even if it's set to NoneType).

Comment: My suggestion is to use named parameters when calling `client.service.soap_method(arg1 = x, arg2 = y, arg3 = z)` and just not pass the optional parameter as an argument.

Comment: If you're having this problem while using complex types, I also came across this related question that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388180/suds-generates-empty-elements-how-to-remove-them